# Make my datepicker required and remove it after selecting a date in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make my datepicker to be required when datepicker is null if date is selected then remove the errorprovider control I have all my textboxes to work as I want but I am having a problem to do the same for my datepicker please take a look at my code and let me know what I am missing.

in the form_load i am making the datepicker to start as null but the date errorprovider is not working

```
private void dp_DateCreated_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker datePicker = sender as DateTimePicker;

    if (datePicker.CustomFormat == " ")
    {
        errp_ErrorProvider.SetError(datePicker, (string)datePicker.Tag);
        errorControls.Add(datePicker);
    }
    else
    {
        errp_ErrorProvider.SetError(datePicker, null);
        errorControls.Remove(datePicker);
    }

    btn_Submit.Enabled = errorControls.Count == 0;
}

private void UserApplication_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_AssetTag.Tag = "Please enter information to this field (Asset Tag) is required";
    txt_SerialNumber.Tag = "Please enter information to this field (Serial Number) is required";
    txt_FixDesc.Tag = "Please enter information to this field (Fix Description) is required";
    txt_DateCreated.Tag = "Please enter information to this field (Date Created) is required";
    txt_TestGood.Tag = "please enter information to the field (Tested Good) is required";
    txt_Bad.Tag = "Please enter information to the field (Tested Bad) is required";
    dp_DateCreated.Tag = "Please select a date to the field (Date Created) is required";

    errp_ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink;
    txt_AssetTag_TextChanged(txt_AssetTag, EventArgs.Empty);
    txt_AssetTag_TextChanged(txt_SerialNumber, EventArgs.Empty);
    txt_FixDesc_TextChanged(txt_FixDesc, EventArgs.Empty);
    txt_DateCreated_TextChanged(txt_DateCreated, EventArgs.Empty);
    txt_DateCreated_TextChanged(txt_TestGood, EventArgs.Empty);
    txt_DateCreated_TextChanged(txt_Bad, EventArgs.Empty);
    dp_DateCreated_ValueChanged(dp_DateCreated, EventArgs.Empty);


    dp_DateCreated.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dp_DateCreated.CustomFormat = " ";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a space in the `CustomFormat == " "` ?

Comment: It was just for testing, but I need to add validation for the datepicker. the errorprovider its not working as I want it

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to check the datepicker for nulls?  In which case, `if (datePicker.Date == null)` should do the trick.  Or perhaps `datePicker.Value`  I forget if the Date property can be null.

Comment: Only you can set a `DateTimePicker` to null. The user will not be able to set an invalid date.

Comment: That is not working, my datepicker starts with no date so I want the errorprovider to show like my other textboxes. if the user then select a date the errorprovider will go away. I tried the if(datePicker.Value == null) and that didn't work.

Comment: I see you are setting the `DateTimePicker` to display a blank value, even though this value is displayed blank... there is STILL a valid date there, namely today's date. So again, the `DataeTimePicker` can NOT have an invalid date. When do you want this date to be displayed? After the user picks a date?

Comment: Yes, only show the date when the user selects the date he wants. so when I run my program the datepicker will be blank and required, once the user selects his date then remove the required errorprovider